# Mapbox Turn-By-Turn Walking directions Android

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

Hi so I'm very new to mapbox so please forgive if this is simple, I'm having real issues with the turn-by-turn navigations. Is it possible to have walking turn-by-turn navigations? From what I've seen it ways it is possible but I can't find any code of how to actually implement it. I have managed to have the route displayed on the map be the walking route, but when I enter the turn-by-turn section I can only get it to work with driving directions.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
Point origin = originPosition;
Point destination = destinationPosition;

String awsPoolId = null;
boolean simulateRoute = true;

NavigationViewOptions options = NavigationViewOptions.builder()
  .origin(origin)
  .destination(destination)
  .awsPoolId(awsPoolId)                
  .profile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_WALKING) //THIS LINE BREAKS CODE (Error:(179, 33) error: cannot find symbol method profile(String))
  .shouldSimulateRoute(simulateRoute)
  .build();

  NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MainActivity.this, options);
}
```

.profile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_WALKING) is the line that is causing the problem. I used this to show walking directions vs driving on the map, so I assumed it's the same for turn-by-turn but it's not working. Can someone enlighten me? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.directionsProfile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_DRIVING_TRAFFIC)
```

instead of

```
.profile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_WALKING)
```